# RSpec controller inherited with base controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec3

I have this in my controller:

```
class API::UsersController < API::BaseController
```

And I generated rspec for this but I kept getting error with:

> uninitialized constant API::BaseController (NameError)

This is what I did in rpsec. What is wrong here. Thanks!

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe API::UsersController do

end
```

Comment: try add type `describe API::UsersController, type: :controller  do
`

Comment: That is the first thing that you can see if you generate a specific controller on rspec. And that is not the problem, the problem is my controller inherited on `API::BaseController` not in `ApplicationController`.